# It is possible to redirect SSD writes to RAM?

Tags: memory, ssd

Wanting to reduce wear on my SSD, I'm wondering if it's possible to redirect, after a clean system installation, all writes to RAM. So I could benefit of my SSD without degradation.
Any ideas?

Comment: What OS? Do you want changes to be flushed to SSD before shutdown? Or start anew each time you boot?

Comment: In 2019, SSDs often specify endurance, so that you can reliably write that much to it every day for years without worry.  Other parts of the system are likely to break first if you're staying at normal low levels of writing.  If you do have a specific high-disk-write program, and don't mind losing everything when power is lost, then set up a RAM disk, and put that specific program's files on the RAM disk.  The specifics are dependent on your OS and the specific program.

Comment: Create a Ramdrive, copy your apps and data to it, run them from the Ramdrive. Are you using MacOS, Windows 10, or Linux (and which brand and version number)?  Need that info to provide specific answer. Please click [edit] and put that essential info into your question with [edit] so all may see it.